# highlight neighbourhood in google map?

Tags: php, google-maps

i m implementing Google map api in PHP website, i have to implement an application in which if user enter some area( specific ) then we have to `highlight all neighbourhood's boundries` of this area with different colors. how do i implement this???

i have read [this link](http://blog.newsplore.com/2009/03/01/602-revision-125) , this helps me a lot, but i need to highlight neighbour reigon of specific area.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the Google Maps API for [Styled Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#StyledMaps).

It lets you change the style (color, etc) of [different map features](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapTypeStyleFeatureType), like neighborhoods.

Answer (score 0):

If you [geocode the location with google](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) it will return coordinates for the southwest and northeast corners. You can use these 2 items to create an overlay over the neighborhood.